# SelectedIndex not updating WPF TabControl via double-click, but does update on a button press

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol, selectedindex

So, I have a tab control:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,-2,0,0" Padding="0" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
```

with the datacontext set to a view model containing:

```
        private int _selectedIndex;
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }
```

On one of the tab items, I have a page that takes the view model from the tab control as it's data context:

```
<Frame Source="Example.xaml" DataContext="{Binding}" LoadCompleted="Frame_LoadCompleted" DataContextChanged="Frame_DataContextChanged"/>
```

Inside that page, I have a DataGrid containing a list of items with a double-click event set:

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenExampleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**And** a button further below:

If I trap the command 'OpenExampleCommand', both call the same method that updates the SelectedIndex value. However, the tab control only changes to a different index via the button click, the double-click never updates the tab control.

If I put a break on the changing of the selected index, double-click the data grid and then hit the button, before the button changes the selected index I can see it's already been changed by the double-click.

So, my question is, why isn't the tab control updating correctly? Both notify exactly the same way?

Comment: first test _selectedIndex != value; before setting it the viewmodel...then what is the code of the command ?

Comment: Done. And the command literally just sets something like:

SelectedIndex = 5

I'd like to use an enum, but since it doesn't work from inside a grid I want to get this fixed first.

Comment: next, the double click put the grid in edit mode and perhaps does not allow the tab to have the focus. try to put your grid in Editable = false

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work. But perhaps you are right, it's not shifting the tab control as we have focus on the grid. I'll try by changing the focus before changing the index.

Comment: No luck with changing the focus, nor setting these:

IsReadOnly="True"
Focusable="False"

Comment: try another event like MouseRightButtomUp

Comment: No luck. I hate to say it, but for the moment maybe I need to just handle the double-click as normal, and then make a call to a method in the ViewModel. Breaks MVVM, but actually works for the user.